# How to set Control.Bar position in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, javascript, ol-ext

I have a control.Bar in OpenLayers  and I would like to set the position.

[EDIT]
I changed my code and now I can set the control in the correct position. However, if I have more than one control and I set them all in the same left position, one is on top of the other. How to solve forever go adding to the side?

```
var control_bar_measure = new ol.control.Bar({group: true});
var control_bar_draw = new ol.control.Bar();
control_bar_draw.setPosition('ol-left');
control_bar_measure.setPosition('ol-left');
```

Comment: `control_bar_measure.setPosition('left')` should work, so there must be something else wrong in you code. Do you have `ol-ext.css` include?

Comment: Yes, I have `ol-ext.css` included. I already use the `ol-ext` library. That's why I found it strange not to work only to set position. I add this control, as per the click of a button. Would you have a problem with that?